# How to print value of a global variable using a method in OOP?

Tags: java

I can't print value of a global variable using a new method.. the error message is `identifier expected and illegal start of type`.

Comment: Help us help you - please share the exact error message and the code that causes it

Comment: share some code

Comment: Looking at similar questions the cause of the error is probably that you have code (assignments) outside of a method on class level but until you post some code we can’t know for sure

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If i am able to understand your question-
You have to declare the global variable static. Only then you can fetch the variable for some operation.
You cannot make a static reference to a non-static field.

Below is a screenshot of the code.

screenshot link-[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S7ZD.jpg)

Comment: Don’t post code as an image, post it as text.

Comment: Ooh shit.. now i can understand problem is variable declaration..

Comment: To show the result I needed to post it as image @joakim

Comment: No you never need to do that, you can add the output separately as text as well. An image like that doesn't prove anything anyway.